# Can not query foreign key related objects using _set | Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

can not access foreignkey related objects , showing error

i have crated instance of Hospital and Availablity   , But while querying using **H1.availablity_set.all()**

```
 //error 
'Hospital' object has no attribute 'availablity_set'
```

**models.py**

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'City')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Availablity(models.Model):
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='availablities')
    facility = models.ForeignKey(Facility, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='facilities')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    available = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**code**

Answer (score 2):

For your `hospital` field of the `Availablity` (sec), you used [**`related_name='availablities'`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), this is the name of the relation in reverse, you thus access the `Availability`s for a `Hospital`:

```
my_hospital.availablities.all()
```

Your model classes and `related name`s have some spelling mistakes. Consider renaming `Availablity` to `Availability`, `related_name='availablities'` to `related_name='availabilities'`. Furthermore it (usually) does not make much sense to give the `related_name` the *same* name is the `ForeignKey` itself, since that is how you query in *reverse*. It is thus better to rename the `relaed_name` to:

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    # …
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='city_hospitals'
    )
```